# Which font produces 1 and l that look similar in math mode?

Tags: fonts

I am looking for a font that produces number 1 and letter l that look similar (with naked eyes) in math mode. Is there such font?

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
    f(x)=
    \begin{cases}
        \frac{x^2+2kx+l}{x+1} & x<-1\\
        x^2+2 & x\geq -1
    \end{cases}
\]
Find $k$ such that $f(x)$ is continuous at $x=-1$. 
\end{document}
```

[image]

If I can make the letter l look similar to number 1 then there will be many students get trapped. :-)

Comment: Except for the blind

Comment: Your joke makes my day :))

Comment: Why would you want to trap students?

Comment: @egreg: I want to train them to work more carefully, especially after get graduated and work in the real life. :-)

Comment: I agree that much of what many students learn is useless in working life, but this is just adding to the list of useless stuff.

Comment: @alephzero: Some of benefits of learning mathematics: confidence, problem-solving skill, deep analysis, critical and systematical thinking, persistent work under pressure, etc. They are very useful in real life. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am still waiting for other better answer. Here is my own solution.

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
    f(x)=
    \begin{cases}
        \frac{x^2+2kx+\mathrm{l}}{x+1} & x<-1\\
        x^2+2 & x\geq -1
    \end{cases}
\]
Find $k$ such that $f(x)$ is continuous at $x=-1$. 
\end{document}
```

[image]

## Edit

Feel free to add other good ones.

```
\documentclass[border=12pt,12pt,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
Evaluate 
$\displaystyle
\lim_{x\to \mathrm{l}}\frac{x^2-\mathrm{l}}{x-1}
$.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The last `l` must be squared. I forgot. Someday I will fix it.